# Setup 'git diff' for special file types

Tags: git, diff

I want to manage Excel files in one of my repositories. Diffing them is a problem (they are binary files). However, there is a nice tool for diffing them: https://github.com/na-ka-na/ExcelCompare

I wanted to set it up using `.gitattributes`

```
*.xls diff=excel
*.xlsx diff=excel
```

And in the `.git/config`:

```
[diff "excel"]
    textconv = excel_cmp.bat
```

The command `excel_cmp.bat file1.xls file2.xls` works very well. However, the setup I use above seems to try to convert the excel files to text using `excel_cmp.bat` and then diffs the text output.

How do I setup the diff tool to diff two files - and not to convert to text first and then diff the text output?

**EDIT:**

In the above setting, what git seems to do is to diff the output of `excel_cmp.bat <file1>` and `excel_cmp.bat <file2>`. But what I want is `excel_cmp.bat <file1> <file2>`. How can I set this up?

Comment: Does the diff tool do that regardless of whether you use it in git ot not? Perhaps you should contact the asuthor on github.

Comment: In my current setting, the difftool is called by git with just one parameter. It expects two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, what I was looking for was the following in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[diff "excel"]
    command = excel_cmp.bat
```

Comment: Where did you place the excel_cmp.bat file?

Answer (score 1):

We've built an open-source Git command line extension for Excel workbooks: https://www.xltrail.com/git-xltrail (the repository is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/git-xltrail) which might help you. It's a simple installation process and does not require any manual plumbing work.

In a nutshell, the main feature is that it makes `git diff` work on any workbook file formats so that it shows the diff on the workbook's VBA content (at some point, we'll make this work for the worksheets content, too).

Comment: Support for Linux/LibreOffice?