# PR diff in bitbucket

Tags: git, pull-request, git-diff, bitbucket-server

We have bitbucket server version 7.6.1 and have created a PR. This PR contains few excel files and pdf's. When I view the PR Diff view(in UI) I could only find the diff as 'old' and 'new' and not line by line difference. Whereas for text and code files line by line diff is presented. This is causing difficulty for us, please suggest if there a way to view line by line diff for pdf's & excel as well in bitbucket ?

Comment: This will help for Excel files, but not for PDF ones: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20069976/3216427

Comment: In general, if you can provide a converter from a binary file format to a text file, Git will do the diff for you on the text representation, but that will always be an imperfect diff since it will rely on whatever the text extractor produces to compute the diff. Nonetheless, I use the technique in that answer for MS Word documents and Excel documents to get diffs that are satisfying to me.

Answer (score 0):

PDF and Excel files are binary files (as opposed to text files), it's almost impossible to compute a meaningful diff for binary files.

This is not specific to Bitbucket or even Git.